How to access the application that's exposed by kubectl
I'm learning k8s and following this tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/
My PC: Macbook Pro M2
Summary steps:

Start K8S cluster


minikube start


Create a deployment


kubectl create deployment kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1


Expose deployment as a service


kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type="NodePort" --port 8080


Access the application


kubectl get nodes -o wide // Get node ip INTERNAL-IP : 192.168.49.2 , EXTERNAL-IP : none


kubectl get services kubernetes-bootcam // Get service port : 8080:31677/TCP


curl http://192.168.49.2:31677 // NO response

I don't know why I can't access to the service by this way.
I tried to expose service by kubectl port-forward deployments/kubernetes-bootcamp 8080:8080 or use minikube minikube service kubernetes-bootcamp, the both ways is worked.

Try accessing the application via the defined node-port: http://192.168.49.2:8080.

@Turing85 I tried but it didn't work, 8080 is internal port that exposed from container, and I mapped this port to external port 31677, so 31677 should be worked. However, it's not worked as my expectation

Not really. You exposed the service with a node port of 8080 through kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type="NodePort" --port 8080, so the application should be available on the node's port 8080.

I recommend reading https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/. It describes two ways to expose your application in minikube.

Thanks @Turing85, however, as I described above, I could exposed deployment by minikube service or kubectl port-forward. Only kubectl expose doesn't worked

I also tried create a service with LoadBalancer type and start the tunnel by minikube tunnel to get external_ip, try to call 127.0.0.1:NODE_PORT or MINIKUBE_IP:NODE_PORT, both doesn't work

This looks more like a https://devops.stackexchange.com/ question.

@tevemadar your url just redirect to home page, please double check

Yes, that's the homepage of the site where this question could rather be asked. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kubernetes/info

Ah thanks, I thought it's post that resolved same my issue
